# Map tiles are sometimes missing when the App enters foreground

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I have an iOS App running on iPhone that display an Apple Map thanks to MKMapView. I'm adding annotations and overlays and it's working well.

Except... when the application goes background and next comes back to foreground. When it happens sometimes the map have missing tiles and the user has to pinch or move the map to reload it.
This issue is not systematic but it happens too frequently!

Is there something I need to do when my App is restarted from the background to make sure the MKMapView is correctly refreshed?
Thanks,

Sebastien